# jq select compare case insensitive

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I have a json file that looks like the following:

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "some_id_1",
            "name": "job_get_re_Log",
            "type": "standard",
            "workspace": {
                "id": "some_id_2",
                "name": "Shared",
                "description": "",
                "type": "custom",
                "environment": {
                    "id": "some_id_3",
                    "name": "DEV"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To get the id (some_id_1), I run the following command:

```bash
name="job_get_re_log"
workspace="Shared"
environment="DEV"

id=$(echo $jsonFile | jq -r ".items[] | select(.name == \"$name\" and .workspace.name == \"$workspace\" and .workspace.environment.name == \"$environment\").id")

echo "$id"
```

As you can see the name variable is "job_get_re_log" but the name in the json is "job_get_re_Log" (capital L). This ends up failing and returning nothing because it's looking for an exact match.

How can I modify the select command so it compares without considering the case (case insensitive)?

Comment: BTW, `echo $jsonFile` is itself buggy; if your file contains `"name": " * "`, f/e, the `*` will be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory. **Always** quote your expansions: `echo "$jsonFile"`

Comment: (Sufficiently standards-compliant versions of `echo` will also try to expand backslashes even without `-e` being present; this is also true of bash's built-in version when both `posix` and `xpg_echo` runtime flags are set -- so when you want to be 100% sure your data will be represented accurately, better to stay away from `echo` altogether and use something like `printf '%s\n' "$jsonFile"` instead).

Comment: Anyhow -- if you read https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/, you'll see that jq has `ascii_downcase` and `ascii_upcase` functions. Do that to both strings, and there you are.

Comment: (Also, better to make your jq code a constant string and pass `$name` and `$environment` with `jq --arg name "$name" --arg environment "$environment"` to keep values out-of-band from code; that way a malicious name can't be used for injection attacks; for that matter, `--arg name "${name,,}"` with a version of bash new enough to support that expansion and you only need to downcase `.name` and not `$name` in jq)

Comment: Thanks for all the information! This was really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `test/1` to check for equality ignoring case, you would have to anchor the
regex string.  Assuming $name has no special regex characters:

```
jq -r --arg w "$workspace" --arg e "$environment" --arg n "$name" '
  .items[]
  | select( (.name | test("^\($n)$"; "i")) and
            (.workspace.name == $w) and
            (.workspace.environment.name == $e)) 
  | .id'
```

The point of using `test/1` of course is that it handles typographical case outside the ASCII range, e.g.

```
$ jq 'test("Å";"i")' <<< '"å"'
true
```

---

As pointed out by @OguzIsmail, if you wish to use `test` even if `$name` might contain regex-special characters, you could use the `\Q...\E` escape mechanism, as in:

```
$ jq 'test("\\Q.\\E")' <<< '"a"'
false
```

Comment: You don't need to de-regex manually https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/SYNTAX.md#0-onig_syn_op2_esc_capital_q_quote-enable-qe

Comment: @OguzIsmail - Tx, I did not know that.

Answer (score 2):

Using `test()` function and `if ... then ... else` statement:

```
<file jq -r --arg w "$workspace" --arg e "$environment" --arg n "$name" \
      '.items[] | if ((.name | test($n; "i")) and (.workspace.name == $w) and (.workspace.environment.name == $e)) then .id else empty end'
```

The insensitive search is done with the flag `"i"` given to `test`.

Comment: +1, but a regex test in place of a string equality test is something I'm not quite sure about. Wouldn't it be less fault-prone to convert both strings to lower-case and do a simple equality comparison? If a name is `fooproject+extensionA`, you don't want `+` to take on its regex meaning.

Comment: I think there's a bug with this command. When I pass "job_get_re", it still matches and returns "some_id_1" when it shouldn't. It should be matching the whole word.

Comment: One could add a `^` at the beginning and a `$` at the end to anchor. The bigger concern is correct escaping.